# Why switch doesn't work while if statement does work

Tags: javascript

I need some help about what's wrong with switch in the following easy script.

```
var pp = 1;
switch (pp) {
    case pp == 1:
        var p = "A";
        break;
    default:
        var p = "F";
        break;
}

document.write(p); //display "F" ---??? it should be "A".

if (pp == 1) document.write("A"); //display "A"
```

Comment: case 1  not case pp==1

Comment: Thank you all guys~ so kind for new starters like me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the [`switch - case`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) syntax in a wrong way,

```
  switch(pp){
      case 1  : var p="A"; break;
      default : var p="F"; break;
  }
```

You could also write your code like below,

```
var p = pp ? "A" : "F"; //And this code is valid for your given data only.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are re-evaluating the value of pp.

Should be

```
case 1:
....
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Switch-cause should follow this format

```
switch(expression) {
case n:
    code block
    break;
case n:
    code block
    break;
default:
    default code block
}
```

so,case pp==1 is in wrong format.it should be correct as follows

```
<script>
          var pp=1;
          switch(pp){
              case 1  : var p="A"; break;
              default : var p="F"; break;
          }
          document.write(p);

          if (pp==1) document.write("A");

   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you definitely need you make a reevaluation for every cases you can pass `true` as expression to the [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement:

```js
var p,
    pp = 1;

switch (true) {
    case pp === 1:
        p = 'A';
        break;
    default:
        p = 'F';
}

console.log(p); // p should be "A"

if (pp === 1) {
    console.log('A'); // display "A"
}
```